# Python-3.x: How to use '\t' "horizontally"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
for i, j in cards: # cards = a list containing list of cards - RANDOM OUTPUTS
        print(i)
        print(j)
        print("\t")
```

How do I make it so that the output becomes:

```
TS  6S  JS
AH  5S  AS
```

Instead of:

```
TS
AH

6S
5S

JS
AS
```

EDIT: changes made above - further specified for the type of code I'm writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i, j in lst:
    print (i + '\t' + j)
```

Output:

```
1   2
2   3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatting:

```
for i in [['1', '2'], ['2', '3']] :
    print('{}\t{}'.format(*i))
```

Output:

```
1   2
2   3
```